# Get object rotationZ / roll

Tags: actionscript-3, air, rotation, away3d

so there’s the camera which is rotated using pitch, yaw, roll and some 90 degrees rotations in various axes. What I’m looking for is the roll value of the camera after the entire transformation. rotationZ property returns not what I’m looking for because it looks like the camera is pitched first, so sometimes the values is 180 degrees despite the camera down vector points downwards.

I’ll gladly provide more information, because I’m stuck :/

Comment: may be you need to use radians?

Comment: what do you mean exactly? away3d seems to work in degrees, how radians change anything?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with. It's not even far from perfect, because it gives only average roll, but for my project's purpose it's enough.

```
var rotation:Number = 0;
var mtx:Matrix3D = _targetCamera.transform.clone();
_cameraRotationObject.transform = mtx;

while (1 == 1)
{
    var lastY:Number = _cameraRotationObject.rightVector.y;
    rotation += 10;
    mtx.appendRotation(-10, _cameraRotationObject.forwardVector, _cameraRotationObject.position);
    _cameraRotationObject.transform = mtx;
    if (lastY > 0 && _cameraRotationObject.rightVector.y <= 0) break;
    lastY = _cameraRotationObject.rightVector.y;
}
```